# Django/Postgres: Parameterized Queriy does not work

Tags: sql, django, postgresql

i have just started diving into raw queries in django.

i am trying to change a schema name in my `postgres`, but my `SQL` query does not work

here's the code that i run in `django shell`:

```
>>> from django.db import connection
>>> cursor = connection.cursor()
>>> query = "ALTER SCHEMA %s RENAME TO %s;"
>>> data = ('thor', 'thor1')
>>> cursor.execute(query, data)
```

Error:

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: syntax error at or near "'thor'"
LINE 1: ALTER SCHEMA 'thor' RENAME TO 'thor1';
```

i believe that those `quotes` are the root of my problem.

any idea how can i make this work ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't use query parameters here as they'll add single quotes which are not supported by postgres.

Try:

```py
>>> from django.db import connection
>>> cursor = connection.cursor()
>>> data = ('thor', 'thor1')
>>> query = """ALTER SCHEMA %s RENAME TO %s;""" % data
>>> cursor.execute(query)
```

Comment: So i can use `Parameterized queries` anywhere else ?

Comment: This might help: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/sql/

Comment: Thank you, i'll look into it later.

Comment: Can I know the usecase? You could get data from the requests and use this setup to achieve the result you want.

Comment: just experimenting, nothing serious :D

Comment: Oh. It's rare to see someone trying to alter the schema using parameters!

Comment: Quarantine makes you do weird  things you know !!